# Is it possible to find an explicit equation for this maximum likelihood for a particular variable of mean function

Tags: self-study, multivariate-normal-distribution, derivative, differential-equations, matrix-calculus

I have a log-likelihood equation that involves multivariate normal. Let's say, $le = \sum_{i=1}^n logf(y_i)$ and
$f(y)=(2\pi)^{-\dfrac{n}{2}}|\sigma^2I_n|^{-\dfrac{1}{2}}exp[-\dfrac{1}{2}(y-x(t))^T|\sigma^2I_n|^{-1}(y-x(t))]$ and x(t) is a very complicated function of c(let's say x(t)=g(c)) which involve exponentials, integration. Is it possible to find an explicit solution for c (not x)? If not, how to solve/find an estimating equation for c? The actual expression of g(c) is  $x(t) = g(c) = \dfrac{exp[b(t)c + b(t)au]}{\int_u exp[b(s)c + b(s)au]ds}$.

$f'(y)=(2\pi)^{-\dfrac{n}{2}}|\sigma^2I_n|^{-\dfrac{1}{2}}exp[-\dfrac{1}{2}(y-g(c))^T|\sigma^2I_n|^{-1}(y-g(c))]*constant*(y-g(c))*g'(c)$. Not sure how to proceed from here. I have done two more steps but ended up with nothing(not an explicit equation for c). If it's not the right way, can someone guide me(give an idea) on which approach I should follow?

Comment: Without knowing $g(c)$, it's pretty obvious we won't be able to help you find an analytical expression for $g^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Can you help us understand why you can't take the log of the likelihood?

Comment: Is this homework, by the way?  If so, please add the "self-study" tag...

Comment: @JohnMadden edited the question.

Comment: @jbowman edited the question.

Comment: Life will be a lot easier if we look at $\frac{\partial}{\partial c} \log f(y;c)$ rather than $\frac{\partial}{\partial c} f(y;c)$. I'm assuming $b(t), a, u$ are all known constants? I don't know of an analytic solution, but numerically a good place to start would be to write this as a nonlinear least squares problem (by just taking the log of the likelihood) and then applying Gauss Newton https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm

Comment: @JohnMadden, we won't be able to find an analytical solution even after taking the log, right? Also not sure if we take log, wouldn't it be the log of log as the LF already include log. I was thinking about numerical ways but was not quite sure.

Comment: I can't rule it out, but it's not obvious to me how to form an analytic solution. You take the log at the beginning of your question, but later on you have the standard derivative rather than the logarithmic derivative. I'm not suggesting you take the log twice, I'm simply suggesting that you consistently take the log.